# Direct kernel boot option in virt manager

Tags: remote-debugging, qemu

I installed `Ubuntu18.04` desktop in a kvm-qemu virtualization setup and it is working. I found that there is a direct kernel boot option in virt-manager settings for a virtual machine. I want to debug the kernel using gdb from the host.

[image]

Please help in finding the `kernel` path and `initrd.img` file path.

Is kernel path same as `arch/x86/boot/bzImage` ?.  Is it possible to copy the `initrd.img` file inside the guest (`/boot/ directory`) to the host machine?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use these options. They are not meant for normal installations. Leave them blank.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually I want this to happen for debugging purpose. I already did it with `qemu-system` and `remote gdb`. I wanted to know whether is it possible using `virt-manager` or not?

Comment: You should continue doing it that way, then, even with virt-manager. You can use `virsh qemu-monitor-command` to enable remote debugging for a VM.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on it? I am new to `virsh`

Comment: okay, I figured out how to correctly ssh into the VM or actually how to boot the VM without using the Direct Boot option which is actually more difficult then using it with just about any generic kernel matching the distro.

Answer (score 2):

> Please help in finding the kernel path and initrd.img file path.

To find currently running kernel you can do this: `cat /proc/cmdline`.
It contains "Kernel command line parameters" and you should find there path to the currently running kernel file. More info: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/systemd/kernel-command-line.7.en.html

There should be no problem with copying files from guest to host machine, unless I misunderstood your question. There are few ways, you could copy it over ssh, or you could share some directory between host and guest or check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858649/how-can-i-copypaste-from-the-host-to-a-kvm-guest not sure what are your requirements here?

Answer (score 2):

Despite a comment above, using the Direct Boot option is one of the only ways to get an Ubuntu cloud image to run on virt-manager: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375589/what-are-the-different-versions-available-as-ubuntu-cloud-images

So, there is no way to point those fields to the internal kernel files. But you can use them like they would be normally in any machine by configuring the Virt-manager bios to recognize them. I'm trying to troubleshoot that currently. Basically, it goes Bios>MBR/GPT(bootloader not easily accessible files except using tools like fdisk, cdisk, parted)>Grub. The boot partition, whichever has /boot/grub on it, has to be flagged as 'boot'. Gparted is one way to see that flag, cfdisk also.

You can point those fields to your own kernel files, they are usually roughly compatible. Then use `root=/dev/sda(X)` adjust to your own root path. Get in and use tools like `update-grub` or `efiboot` to configure the image.

EDIT: I finally found the way to make the internal kernel files work for booting the VM in virt-manager. Basically, either install the non-kvm, generic kernel version using `apt install linux-image-$(uname -r)` and change kvm to generic (~90Mb), or use the kvm kernel and ssh into the VM using `systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service && systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service`, then `virtsh console <vm-name>`.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/576437/virsh-ssh-into-a-guest-vm